# About Linux Networking Programming

Tags: linux, echo

i have written the client and server c file to make an echo server program,i wrote it according to the tutorial video, but i can not figure out where i made the mistakes

```
//this is the client.c
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(void)
{
    int  sock;
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        printf("socket establish fail!");

    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(30000);
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))<0)
         printf("connect failed");

    char sendbuf[1024] = { 0 };
    char recvbuf[1024] = { 0 };

    while (fgets(sendbuf,sizeof(sendbuf),stdin) != NULL)
    {
        write(sock, sendbuf, sizeof(sendbuf));
        read(sock, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf));
        //fputs(recvbuf, stdout);
        printf("%s",recvbuf);
        memset(sendbuf, 0, sizeof(sendbuf));        
        memset(recvbuf, 0, sizeof(recvbuf));
    }
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
//this is the server.c
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(void)
{
    int  listenfd, conn;
    struct sockaddr_in peeraddr;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    socklen_t peerlen = sizeof(peeraddr);
    char recvbuf[1024];

    if ((listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        printf("socket establish fail!");

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    memset(&recvbuf, 0, sizeof(recvbuf));   
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(30000);
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if (bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0)
        printf("Bind fail");

    if (listen(listenfd, 5) < 0)
        printf("Listen fail");

    if (conn= accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&peeraddr, &peerlen) < 0)
        printf("accept fail");

    while (1)
    {
        int ret = read(conn, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf));
        //fputs(recvbuf,stdout);
        printf("%s",recvbuf);
        write(conn, recvbuf, ret);
    }

    close(conn);
    close(listenfd);
    return 0;
}
```

i worked for it for several hours but i can not find the answer 
please help me!

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."  That said, For all things network related see [**Beej's Guide to Network Programming**](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/). It is an excellent reference/tutorial for network programming.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment